# Why isn't my margin working?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have been creating a simple sidebar for my website. I want to put a `40px` `margin` next to my main table so it doesn’t look like it’s part of the sidebar.

I have also tried to put a `<div>` around the main area and styled it like this:

```css
margin: 40px;
```

I also have a navigation bar in the way. (I’m fine if you want to make the font size smaller in the navigation bar.) How can I do this?

All Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Open Sans;
      margin: 40px;
    }
    .dateOfPost {
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    form {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      width: 270px;
      height: auto;
      float: left;
    }
    #cssmenu ul {
      background: #f96e5b;
      width: auto;
      list-style: none;
      float: right;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      line-height: 1;
      display: block;
      zoom: 1;
    }
    #cssmenu ul:after {
      content: " ";
      display: block;
      font-size: 0;
      height: 0;
      clear: both;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right ul li {
      float: right;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-center ul {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a {
      font-size: auto;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      padding: 15px 25px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 700;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 14px;
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transition: color .25s;
      -moz-transition: color .25s;
      -ms-transition: color .25s;
      -o-transition: color .25s;
      transition: color .25s;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a:hover {
      color: #333333;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
      width: 100%;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      right: -3px;
      top: 19px;
      height: 6px;
      width: 6px;
      background: #ffffff;
      opacity: .5;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
    #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
      display: none;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li.active a {
      color: #333333;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
      width: 100%;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right li.last > a:after,
    #cssmenu.align-right li:last-child > a:after {
      display: block;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right li:first-child a:after {
      display: none;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      #cssmenu ul li {
        float: none;
        display: block;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a {
        width: 100%;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fb998c;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li.last > a,
      #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a {
        border: 0;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a:after {
        display: none;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a:before {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>
    <p>Please enable Javascript before viewing this page or else some elements may not appear and/or function properly.</p>
  </noscript>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <form id="signUp">
      <p>
        <b>Hey! </b>Want to post comments and receive cool information about me? If You Do, Sign Up Now! :D
        <br />
        <br />Nickname:
        <input type="text" id="nickname" placeholder="Nickname" required>
        <br/>Email Address:
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="254" required>
        <br />Password:
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="confirmAccount">
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="rightColumn">
    <h1>Ryan Zhang's Blog</h1>
    <div id="cssmenu">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="home.html"><span>Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="aboutMe.html"><span>About Me</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="tipsNTricks.html"><span>Tips 'n' Tricks</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="inspiration.html"><span>Inspirational Quotes and       Words</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="timeline.html"><span>Timeline of Me</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum
      <br />Upload Date:
      <br />
      <date>25/10/15</date>
    </p>
    <hr />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "I want to put a 40px margin next to my main table..." there is no table. "so it doesn't look like it's part of the sidebar." what do you mean by sidebar? you need to be very specific or nobody can properly answer.

Comment: u get the point don't you

Comment: `onclick="confirmAccount"` looks like code that doesn’t do anything.

Comment: ill make that code do something later. right now, I am more concerened about the margin.

Comment: @RyanplaysGames i actually don't. i might, but on my first look at this i really had no idea. seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the right column a width and float it to the right. If you can add more of a margin but then the nav wraps to a second line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Open Sans;
      margin: 40px;
    }
    .dateOfPost {
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    h1 {
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    .rightColumn {
      width: 77%;
      float: right;
    }
    form {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      width: 270px;
      height: auto;
      float: left;
    }
    #cssmenu ul {
      background: #f96e5b;
      width: auto;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      line-height: 1;
      display: block;
      zoom: 1;
    }
    #cssmenu ul:after {
      content: " ";
      display: block;
      font-size: 0;
      height: 0;
      clear: both;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right ul li {
      float: right;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-center ul {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a {
      font-size: auto;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      padding: 15px 25px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 700;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 14px;
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transition: color .25s;
      -moz-transition: color .25s;
      -ms-transition: color .25s;
      -o-transition: color .25s;
      transition: color .25s;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a:hover {
      color: #333333;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
      width: 100%;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      right: -3px;
      top: 19px;
      height: 6px;
      width: 6px;
      background: #ffffff;
      opacity: .5;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
    #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
      display: none;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li.active a {
      color: #333333;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
      width: 100%;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right li.last > a:after,
    #cssmenu.align-right li:last-child > a:after {
      display: block;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right li:first-child a:after {
      display: none;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      #cssmenu ul li {
        float: none;
        display: block;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a {
        width: 100%;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fb998c;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li.last > a,
      #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a {
        border: 0;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a:after {
        display: none;
      }
      #cssmenu ul li a:before {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>
    <p>Please enable Javascript before viewing this page or else some elements may not appear and/or function properly.</p>
  </noscript>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <form id="signUp">
      <p>
        <b>Hey! </b>Want to post comments and receive cool information about me? If You Do, Sign Up Now! :D
        <br />
        <br />Nickname:
        <input type="text" id="nickname" placeholder="Nickname" required>
        <br/>Email Address:
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="254" required>
        <br />Password:
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="confirmAccount">
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="rightColumn">
    <h1>Ryan Zhang's Blog</h1>
    <div id="cssmenu">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="home.html"><span>Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="aboutMe.html"><span>About Me</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="tipsNTricks.html"><span>Tips 'n' Tricks</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="inspiration.html"><span>Inspirational Quotes and       Words</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="timeline.html"><span>Timeline of Me</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum
      <br />Upload Date:
      <br />
      <date>25/10/15</date>
    </p>
    <hr />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```